# How do I display a date format in dd/MM/yyyy to ddd, dd/MM/yyyy (Mon, 1/4/2014) format with this logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, date-formatting

Right now I have been given the code below code to get the selected date from a calendar and displays it into a textbox but it's in dd/MM/yyyy format.

```
txtSMAlerted_PopupControlExtender.Commit(calSMAlerted.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: so how do you want the date to be ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simply a format string passed to the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the DateTime

```
 calSMAlerted.SelectedDate.ToString("ddd, dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The ToString(string) overload of DateTime accepts a [Standard Date Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well as a [Custom Date And Time Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
With this last set of rules it is easy to build your required output format.

Comment: Hi, your format will get the date as : Mon, 01/04/2014,isn't it?

Comment: you miss a " mark. and other answer copy yours. look at it.

Comment: Yes exactly, as specified in the link, ToString accepts a standard date format string or a custom date and time format strings

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
calSMAlerted.SelectedDate.ToString("ddd, dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

you should parse datetime into string like this:

```
calSMAlerted.SelectedDate.ToString("ddd, d/M/yyyy");
```

Comment: what will your code if you want to print Mon, 15/04/2014?